# How to interpret iTextSharp TJ/TF result

Tags: itext

I'm implementing an automation process with PowerShell using iTextSharp lib, to extract needed information about several PDF documents.

Based on this PDF content portion:

[image: PDF content portion]

It returns this result:

```
[(1)-1688.21(1)-492.975(0)-493.019(0)]TJ
[(5)-493.019(0)-17728.1(2)]TJ
```

I can extract the literal values with some regex manipulation but, only using this method the result is:

```
$line -replace "^\[\(|\)\]TJ$", "" -split "\)\-?\d+\.?\d*\(" -join ""

1000
502
```

Of course, these results are not integral, and I need more specification on the reading/parsing.
I'm suspecting that the numbers between the literal characters (e.g -1688.21,-492.975,...), may be useful, but I didnt find explanation about such parameters.

What they represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are wondering about details of the PDF format, you should have a look into the PDF specification ISO 32000.

| Operands | Operator | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *array* | **TJ** | Show one or more text strings, allowing individual glyph positioning. Each element of *array* shall be either a string or a number. If the element is a string, this operator shall show the string. If it is a number, the operator shall adjust the text position by that amount; that is, it shall translate the text matrix, *T*<sub>m</sub>. The number shall be expressed in thousandths of a unit of text space (see 9.4.4, "Text Space Details"). This amount shall be *subtracted* from the current horizontal or vertical coordinate, depending on the writing mode. In the default coordinate system, a positive adjustment has the effect of moving the next glyph painted either to the left or down by the given amount. Figure 46 shows an example of the effect of passing offsets to **TJ**. |

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 109 – Text-showing operators)*

Thus,

> I'm suspecting that the numbers between the literal characters (e.g -1688.21,-492.975,...), may be useful, but I didnt find explanation about such parameters.
>
> What they represent?

For each such number, the operator adjusts the text position by that amount. The number is expressed in thousandths of a unit of text space. This amount is *subtracted* from the current horizontal or vertical coordinate, depending on the writing mode.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Done!
"This amount shall be subtracted from the current horizontal or vertical coordinate, depending on the writing mode. " - Can you explain the concept of "writing mode"? This is by the fact I can't relate such values with position, in the case of the two lines I represented above as example.

Comment: @Gui *"Can you explain the concept of "writing mode"? "* - PDF knows both a horizontal  and a vertical writing mode. Your approach seems to imply that you are only extracting Western languages all of which work in horizontal writing mode.

Comment: @Gui By the way, which iTextSharp version are you using? Somewhere in the early 5.x versions iText got a decent text extraction API, so you don't have to deal with content stream details anymore as you do now.